# Wordpress Jetpack Portfolio Post-Type

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I am using the Be-Theme v11 Wordpress Theme and I notice that it comes with Portfolio. However, I was already using Jetpack Portfolio with another theme. I want to either export all my posts from Jetpack over to the Betheme Portfolio or Change the post type from Jetpack so that BeTheme uses the posts from Jetpack instead.

I know that I can re-post them one by one but that would take too long. Also, if I use the BeTheme one instead of the jetpack one, I get a bunch of awesome styling features that comes with BeTheme.

Anyone have a good solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could just change the post-type of the posts created using the Jetpack plugin to that of the new theme. There are a lot of ways to achieve this.

1. You could directly get your hands dirty and achieve this from phpMyAdmin. To do so, login to phpMyAdmin and run the following query:

   ```
   UPDATE  `wp_posts` SET  `post_type` =  'post_type_used_in_betheme' WHERE  `post_type` = 'post_type_used_in_jetpack';
   ```

Remember to modify the code to replace `post_type_used_in_betheme` and `post_type_used_in_jetpack`.

2. Else, use a plugin like [Post Type Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/).
3. Use one of the methods mentioned in this [WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/97026/59124).

Answer (score 0):

I was recently decide to uninstall Jetpack because It causes my website receiving the error: "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds". I had used Jetpack's portfolio option and deleting the pluggin all posts are lost. So before I decided to change the post type from 'jetpack-portfolio' to 'post' and also update the Jetpack tags 'jetpack-portfolio-tag'. Additionally, Jetpack categories must be manually removed and manually reassign new categories to migrated posts.

Update tags:

```
UPDATE `wp_term_taxonomy` 
SET taxonomy = 'post_tag' 
WHERE taxonomy = 'jetpack-portfolio-tag'
```

Migrate portfolio to post:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_type = 'post'
    , guid = concat('https://yourwebsite.com/?p=',ID) 
WHERE post_type = 'jetpack-portfolio';
```